# SBT not loading properly in Intellij-Idea (no SBT external Imports)

Tags: macos, scala, intellij-idea, sbt

The issue I have is with a particular scala project of mine when it comes to using the imports from my .sbt file. What I expect to happen is when I open up my project by selecting

> Open > New Project > Select my SBT

is that my dependencies are loaded as per usual and everything outlines in my SBT file can be found in the project's External Libraries.

When I do import the project I am prompted to update the SBT it indicates that its updating everything and pulling from the SBT sources, but in reality it does not actually reflect any imported items (which also leaves my build.sbt file to have red-underline items as these libraries have not been imported).

A sample of the External Libraries:

[image: external libraries]

A sample from my build.sbt:

[image: build.sbt]

I have uninstalled, re-installed both IntelliJ and all the plugins, removed my SBT items, added them in again, restarted, rinse repeat until infinity.

I've also opened up the SBT tools window and refreshed SBT as well as removed everything from the list and added it in again with no success.

With that, I have also deleted the generated .idea file and re-imported the project multiple times, using multiple different settings. (Removing the .idea file every time I tried something new).

I have tested the exact same project on a colleague's machine with working results, so I am not sure if there's anything I have configured incorrectly. We compared but everything looks exactly the same.

Cleaning, compiling and running the SBT in terminal works 100% - and this issue does NOT persist when I create a new Scala project. Theres also no error output which is REALLY frustrating.

I've tested with the following:

> IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.1 (Ultimate Edition)
>
> Build #IU-181.4445.20, built on April 2, 2018
>
> JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b27 x86_64
>
> JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
>
> macOS 10.13.3
>
> Scala Plugin 2018.1.8
>
> scala v2.12.4
>
> SBT 1.1.1

** EDIT
To give more information, when I have a simple build.sbt file (aka I give it a scala version, a name and some library dependencies) it works completely fine.

When I start adding in different aggregates under the root, it appears to stop recognising those modules.

As an example, I have;

```
lazy val root = Project("scala-test", file("."))
  .aggregate(core)
```

If I check my SBT side panel I see everything listed:

[image]

Yet they are not in my project structure, meaning that it does not recognise any of the internal imports or import paths:

[image]

It appears to be something that's wrong with the Scala plugin but I have not found a stable solution around this.

Comment: views -> Tools windows and Select sbt -> then a panel will open on right side of the ide -> Click on the circle button and you won't see this error in ide again.

Comment: I've tried updating SBT by using the SBT panel on the right - the same issue is still there.

Comment: Are you using 2018.1? There seems to be a bug in it. I used to be able to switch to Intellij and it would automatically recognize changes to build.sbt, but it doesn't do that anymore, unless I make the change to build.sbt inside Intellij itself. Or simply close and reopen Intellij. They need to fix this ASAP.

Comment: I had also a problem with sbt / intellij - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49815909/not-a-valid-command-idea-shell-similar-shell-oldshell - maybe this helps (cannot tell for sure as your sbt console output is not in the ticket)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a very similar problem when upgrading from IntelliJ-Idea 2017.3 to 2018.1

My temporary solution was to revert back to the 2017 version.
I found this bug in their bug tracker which I think relates to the problem.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-13600

Have you tried with an older version or found a more permanent solution to this yet?

Comment: I'm just adding this comment here if anyone else bumps into this question - downgrading was the only way I solved this problem previously - but I haven't had this issue in the latest versions going forward.

Answer (score 21):

Have you also removed `.idea` folder and opened the project again.

This helps for me most of the time.

I only use `File -> Open...` then selecting the directory that contains the `build.sbt`.

This is how I configure the new project:

[image: sbt project config]

Comment: Hey, yes I've removed the .idea file as well - as well as removed any target folders it created and in the extreme I even re-cloned the project just to start from scratch.

Comment: Have you also tried another SBT project, e.g. >`sbt new scala/scala-seed.g8`?

Comment: I've re-created the whole project by starting off from scratch and I get the same issue once I start adding in all my dependencies. I'll give a bit more detail in the main post though.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

```sh
cd <project-directory>

# only run this line if you haven't import project into intelij
mkdir -p .idea

touch .idea/sbt.xml

cat > .idea/sbt.xml << EOM
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
    <component name="ScalaSbtSettings">
        <option name="customVMPath" />
        <option name="linkedExternalProjectsSettings">
            <SbtProjectSettings>
                <option name="externalProjectPath" value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
                <option name="modules">
                    <set>
                        <option value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
                        <option value="$PROJECT_DIR$/project" />
                    </set>
                </option>
                <option name="sbtVersion" value="1.4.6" />
            </SbtProjectSettings>
        </option>
    </component>
</project>
EOM
```

I used the sbt version `1.4.6` for my setup but feel free to change it to your preference.

Once you did the following, open the project in intelij and then under menu bar `View/Tool Windows` `sbt` will appear and when you open your `build.sbt` file it will recognise the syntaxes.

Comment: If I recall correctly - at the time this was a bug between the newer version of SBT (newer back then), the version of intellij as well as the version of the plugin that caused the issue - there was a bug which was sorted with either downgrading or using a patch build. This answer may be relevant to users currently experiencing the issue though :)

Answer (score -1):

I also faced similar issue and need to dig around various stack overflow posts to resolve it but found that none of the post mentioned the below solution which actually worked for me.

This issue occurs in cases when you open the root project containing multiple microservices (means multiple .sbt project) in intelliJ.

Points you can check to overcome this issue:

1. Open single microservice project in intellij. You should notice once
   you open, the intelliJ automatically detects it as a sbt project and
   tries to build it.
2. In case the issue occurs in auto build which hinders the download of
   sbt dependencies, you need to cross verify your artifactory url and
   credentials.