# Not a valid command: idea-shell (similar: shell, oldshell)

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I have trouble refreshing my SBT project in Intellij. And I am not the only one.

This is the sbt-console:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=localhost:51917,suspend=n,server=y -Xdebug -server -Xmx1028M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Didea.runid=2017.2 -Didea.managed=true -jar "/Users/pascal.mengelt/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea2018.1/Scala/launcher/sbt-launch.jar" idea-shell
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 51917
[info] Loading settings from idea.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/user/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Loading settings from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/pascal.mengelt/GitHub/scala/scala-adapters-wizard/project
[info] Loading settings from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to wizardDemo (in build file:/Users/pascal.mengelt/GitHub/scala/scala-adapters-wizard/)
[error] Not a valid command: idea-shell (similar: shell, oldshell)
[error] Not a valid project ID: idea-shell
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Not a valid key: idea-shell (similar: daemonShell)
[error] idea-shell
[error]           ^
[INFO] [04/13/2018 13:13:19.377] [Thread-2] [CoordinatedShutdown(akka://sbt-web)] Starting coordinated shutdown from JVM shutdown hook
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I found the Intellij issue for that (with workaround):

[SCL-12430 Not a valid key: idea-shell](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-12430)

> Yes ,delete the `~/.sbt/{0.13|1.0}/plugins/target`

Here the command provided by Mateusz Kubuszok:

```
rm -rf ~/.sbt/{0.13,1.0}/plugins/target
```

Comment: Deleting <user home>/.sbt/0.13/plugins/target/streams/$global/ worked for me.

Comment: Because I have to run this command every now and then I'll just put here for future copy-paste: `rm ~/.sbt/{0.13,1.0}/plugins/target -rf` (changed `|` -> `,` and added `-rf`)

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok thanks - I added it to my answer - I had to move `-rf` that it worked on my mac

Comment: I figured out how to get `sbt-idea-shell` to work again (for me). If you are using `sbt-coursier`, you have to use the proper setting re: installed as the only plugin vs. installed alongside other plugins. It had been installed as "alongside other plugins" and after I changed the `sbt-coursier` plugin setup to "as the only plugin," then `sbt-idea-shell` started working again. See the `sbt-coursier` docs for detailed info on the different configurations.